# A sql query to get the data src of linked server

Tags: sql-server

I have a linked server named `[TRNGInsght_EmpHierarchy]`. From this linked server I want to get the data src through a sql-query.

How should I do that? Please help!

Comment: What DBMS do you use?

Comment: What database management system do you use? `SqlServer`, `MySQL`, `Oracle` and so on.

Comment: I'm guessing SQL Server. A 5 second google search turned this up: http://jwcooney.com/2011/10/26/sql-server-how-to-list-the-full-properties-of-all-linked-servers/